# Network related columns (macaddr, cidr etc.) in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, types

We have used postgres in our application witch has a very nice set of network related column types along with functions package to operate on them.

And those columns, like macaddr, cidr etc. are extremely important, as they're used as a PKs or indexes in many tables.

(App is an cable modems provisioning system)

We're forced to move to the oracle instance, is there any way to force oracle to easily operate on network related column datatypes?

How we can handle with ie. getting mac addresses in different textual representations, from various dependent components?

- xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx
- xx.xx.x.x.xx.xx
- xxxx.xxxx.xxxx (cisco way)
- xxxxxxxxxxxx

same with cidrs etc.

Till now, postgres was able to handle that cases in very efficient and nice way...

(I'm new in Oracle RDBMS)

Comment: I'm not sure, because the new company owner hadn't sent us the specification yet, just information, that we'll have to port our app to oracle platform owned by the investor. But i think it'll be the 11g version

Comment: +1, Interesting. Are these types and functions in postgres native to the RDBMS? Or are they add-ons?

Comment: Yep they're native in postgres, out-of-box :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no native datatypes or supplied packages in Oracle for dealing with network structures like this that I am aware of. You'll likely have to create your own TYPE, perhaps using some of Oracle's [Object Type functionality](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/objects.htm#i12884). This would seem to be a nice fit for the feature.

[Here's an overview](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-objects.html).